# Why SQL Server has error when i use LIKE operator?

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I want to select employees that have the third character of the first name is ‘l’ (as image below)
After executing, there are 4 correct record and 1 incorrect.
I dont't understand why that record having first name is 'Philip' with l is fourth character is selected?

[My SQL Statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljn8B.png)

Comment: can you provide output of `select fname, SUBSTRING(fname, 3, 1) as sb, ascii(SUBSTRING(fname, 3, 1)) as asb
from employee
where fname like '__l%'`

Comment: Please avoid posting image. Post as formatted text

Comment: I'd be keen to see the output of `select cast(fname as varbinary(max)) from employee where fname='Philip' and lname='Cramer'` because it sounds like you could have `nchar`/`nvarchar` columns here with weird combining characters.

Comment: it can depend on the COLLATION of your columns. Whisch collation is used for the columns of the table ? Execute : SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to show  the results for your table.

Comment: @IłyaBursov  it has 4 correct record consits of: sb is l and asb is 108. And record containing "Philip" has value: i and 105

Comment: sorry, i am newbie so I'm still not used to formatted text

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It is 0x5068696C6970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a COLLATION specific probleme and those who gave a negative rating indiscriminately should think a little more than instinctively vote!

With the Vietnamese_100_... collation (which I think that is the case for our user HaNgocHieu) or for some others collations like Welsh_100... the Ph two letters are considered as only one and the result is that the query returns also Philip.

As a test :

```
CREATE TABLE #employee  
( fname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  lname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #employee(fname,lname) 
VALUES ('Philip','Cramer');

SELECT *
FROM  #employee  e  
where fname + lname COLLATE Vietnamese_CI_AI LIKE '__l%';

fname                lname
-------------------- --------------------
Philip               Cramer

SELECT *
FROM  #employee  e  
where fname + lname COLLATE French_CI_AI LIKE '__l%';

fname                lname
-------------------- --------------------

SELECT *
FROM  #employee  e  
where fname + lname COLLATE Welsh_100_CI_AI LIKE '__l%';


fname                lname
-------------------- --------------------
Philip               Cramer
```

So SQL Server has no error, nor HaNgocHieu does not make any mistake, but using a specific collations with non specific data can cause some trouble that can be solved in using an international COLLATION like those in latin

Comment: Now, I know what my problem is and I can easily look it up and learn how to fix it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

your data

```
declare @employee TABLE (
   fname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
  ,lname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @employee(fname,lname) VALUES ('Helen','Bennett');
INSERT INTO @employee(fname,lname) VALUES ('Helvetius','Nagy');
INSERT INTO @employee(fname,lname) VALUES ('Palle','Ibsen');
INSERT INTO @employee(fname,lname) VALUES ('Philip','Cramer');
INSERT INTO @employee(fname,lname) VALUES ('Roland','Mendel');
```

for searching in column for specific charachter using CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING would be much better. In Addition, you must choose the best collate ( sorting rules, case, and accent sensitivity properties for your data) in your table such as  COLLATE **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS**
SUBSTRING

```
select concat(fname,' ',lname) as fullname
FROM @employee  e  
where SUBSTRING(fname, 3, 1)='l' and fname SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
ORDER BY e.fname
```

CHARINDEX

```
select concat(fname,' ',lname) as fullname
FROM @employee  e  
where CHARINDEX('l', fname) = 3 and fname SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
ORDER BY e.fname
```

Comment: You do not explain the trouble